# Layer перекрашивает мою view

Tags: ios, swift

Всем привет! У меня есть светло-синяя точка, в коде она userPositionView.
Выглядит она вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда с помощью layer, я "нарисовал" радиус(мол в радиусе 5 метрах находится юсер) для этой светло-синей точки(userPositionView), то layer'у я задал полупрозрачный темно-синий цвет, который и перекрасил мою светло-синюю точку (userPositionView).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
  func setupUserPosition() {
    userPositionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200 , y: 300), size: CGSize(width: 22, height: 22)))
    userPositionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 173/255, blue: 212/255, alpha: 1.0)
    userPositionView.layer.cornerRadius = userPositionView.frame.height / 2
    userPositionView.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
    userPositionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    userPositionView.setupShadow()

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 21/255, green: 45/255, blue: 71/255, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
    layer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: (userPositionView.bounds.width / 2) - (44 / 2), y: (userPositionView.bounds.height / 2) - (44 / 2) )
    cRadius = layer
  }
```

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы мой радиус не перекрашивал мою светло-синюю точку в темный цвет?

Comment: светло-синий круг у вас тоже полупрозрачный?

Comment: @schmidt9 нет, везде стоит альфа 1.0 у userPositionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так - сначала рисовать отдельный слой с большим кругом, а поверх него накладывать уже слой с малым кругом, я это сделал в виде отдельного вью, большой круг равен его размеру, а малый - с отступами 1/4

```
import UIKit

class CircleView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        addLayers()
    }

    func addLayers() {
        layer.sublayers?.forEach({ layer in
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        })

        // outer layer

        let outerCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        outerCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 21/255, green: 45/255, blue: 71/255, alpha: 0.3).cgColor

        let outerCircleLayerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)
        outerCircleLayer.path = outerCircleLayerPath.cgPath

        layer.addSublayer(outerCircleLayer)

        // inner layer

        let innerCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        innerCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 173/255, blue: 212/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        innerCircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        innerCircleLayer.lineWidth = 2.5

        let inset = frame.width / 4
        let innerCircleLayerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: inset, left: inset, bottom: inset, right: inset)))
        innerCircleLayer.path = innerCircleLayerPath.cgPath

        layer.addSublayer(innerCircleLayer)
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если обязательно чтобы синий круг был view? Как в этом случае можно сделать? Можете добавить пример в ответ?

Comment: @MikeMclaren сделать вью-контейнер, где будет одно вью для фона (большого круга) и другое для синего круга поверх него